# Why does AWS warn "Do not grant public read access to this object(s) (Recommended)"

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is the only way to make files/images available to everyone on your website - otherwise they won't be able to see it. Same with css files if they arn't publicly readable then the website won't have styling so why does it warn to not grant access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It warns everyone, because lots of people make the wrong things public by accident - check the news lately - but if you are serving up web content, you can safely ignore the warning....